# Adding taxes - paypal variables

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm trying to add taxes to my paypal settings for my shopping cart.

Here's what I got in the Javascript code:

```
//static paypal request arguments
            var pp_settings = {
                cmd: '_cart',
                upload: 1,
                no_note: 0,
                bn: 'JQPayPalShop_ShoppingCart_EC_US',
                rm: 2,
                custom: '',
                discount_rate_cart:50,
                tax_rate:9
            };
```

I added "discount_rate_cart" to test if I was adding the variables at the right place, and yes the total is 50% cheaper. So I'm at the right place.

But then, when adding "tax_rate", I can type whatever I want next to it, it's just not working. No taxes added on the checkout page.

Any idea why?

EDIT: For those who wants to see the full code : http://jsfiddle.net/uNV6f/

Comment: could u share jsfiddle for complete code

Comment: Hmmm...sure but my code got thousands of lines. Check the first post for update

Comment: Talk about redundancy. I think you should look into the switch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.  I would also suggest looking into objects because having everything hard coded as you do is not very maintainable.

Comment: Tabarnak, lol ! You can define tax % inside the paypal account if this doesn't work.

Comment: @RobB - I know...but it does what I need and I needed something done as quickly as possible.

Comment: @David Bélanger : Je sais...je sais...! I tried defining the tax % in my Paypal account, but the taxe rate is not appearing on the paypment page...Thank you

Comment: user1388136 Very weird, sorry. Can't help. Idea is do price * 1.09 but you see taxe inside the paiement page.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong variable name. For individual items, it's ok, but it looks like you're trying to set it up for the whole cart.

In that case it should be **`tax_cart`**

Check out this document with the full list of variables that you can use:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH0D0TA

Comment: But tax_cart is just an amount added to the total. I need it to be a percentage. That's why I think I need to use tax_rate.

Comment: Based on the documentation, either you apply a percentage to each individual item, or you apply a whole value to the cart.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I tried something else using tax_rate...and it's working now. I forgot to add something in my code. So it's working now using the "tax_rate" variable.